# How do I resolve a map value called on null

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a contact model that uses maps but the return is null thus causing aysnc suspension. I have tried tried setting these maps to return an empty list but to no avail do I manage to resolve the issue.

```
   ContactModel{
    //factory method constructor 
    emails: List<Email>.from(parsedJson['Emails'].map((x)=>Email.fromJson(x))),
    tasks:  List<Tasks>.from(parsedJson["Tasks"].map((x) => Tasks.fromJson(x))),
    notes: List<Notes>.from(parsedJson["Notes"].map((x) => Notes.fromJson(x))),

     }
```

The error returns as : No such method map called on null. Receiver null

I have tried to resolve the issue by writing it as such

```
ContactModel{
    //factory method constructor 
    emails: List<Email>.from(parsedJson['Emails'].map((x)=>Email.fromJson(x))).toList() ?? [],
    tasks:  List<Tasks>.from(parsedJson["Tasks"].map((x) => Tasks.fromJson(x))).toList() ?? [],
    notes: List<Notes>.from(parsedJson["Notes"].map((x) => Notes.fromJson(x))).toList() ?? [],

     }
```

Comment: Do you mean parsedJson might not have some of the values? e.g. 'Emails'

Comment: No, the error states that the receiver is null and suspends the rest of my function when working with the object type ContactModel

Comment: But where is the function that is stopping?

Comment: `parsedJson` is null in this case so you must check it's not before doing the other operations, like using `if-else`.

Comment: @BélindaG.Freitas, yes, this is what I am asking. I have added ,toList() ?? [], from my understanding, should the return be null, it should set the list to [] an empty list

Comment: No this won't do it. I will paste an example of resolution as answer so it's more readable.

Comment: Thanks @BélindaG.Freitas I look forward to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `null` checking the json like so :

```dart
ContactModel{
    emails: parsedJson['Emails'] != null ? List<Email>.from(parsedJson['Emails'].map((x)=>Email.fromJson(x))).toList() : [],
    tasks: parsedJson['Tasks'] != null ?  List<Tasks>.from(parsedJson["Tasks"].map((x) => Tasks.fromJson(x))).toList() : [],
    notes:parsedJson['Notes'] != null ?  List<Notes>.from(parsedJson["Notes"].map((x) => Notes.fromJson(x))).toList() : [],
}
```

Comment: This is the right one. The answer provided by @Bélinda G. Freitas is similar however using explicit if-else statements seemed to cause an error, using the ternary operator check worked effectively.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I always check 2 things when working with JSON types :

- You must check your JSON contains the key you're looking for
- You must check null value being returned if the key exist.

I recommend you doing this double check like this :

```
if(parsedJson.isNotEmpty) {
  List<dynamic> emails = [];
  if (parsedJson.containsKey('Email') && parsedJson['Email'] is List) {
    emails = List<Email>.from(parsedJson['Emails'].map((x)=>Email.fromJson(x)))
  }
  ContactModel({emails: emails});
}
```

This way, you always make sure you've got the right type, and avoid production error (imagine your API going nuts). It's more verbose, I know, but to me, good code requires accuracy

Comment: This is a phenomenal check and is excellent code practice. I have come across instances where I have misspelt the key and as of today dealing with Null returns. Thank you. @gbnfr